# HTML Iframe Background Image of element not showing - Inline style block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW26M.png
[image]

I set the iframe's innerHTML with

```
iframedoc.body.innerHTML = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

And styles of iframe's elements are in the inline style block.

But when I set the whole document with `document.write(iframedoc.body.innerHTML)` it looks like this:

[image]

And there is the #logo element's style:

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 1170px;
    height: 119px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left:335px;
    background: url(allegroImg/bannerTop2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

What is wrong? Why isn't the background-image displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about the image source, nevermind